# JQuery Slider in django templates

Tags: jquery, html, django, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add a JQuery slider in a Django template but it doesn't work...

My main template:

```
...
<div>
<dt class="nav-header">Size</dt>
    <dd>
        {% include 'catalogue/slider_size.html' %}
    </dd>
</div>
...
```

The template slider_size.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
} );
</script>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

The error in the console:

[Error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcfcI.png)

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what script are included in you main template? it might be duplicated imports

Comment: That's exactly what it is! Duplicated imports... Many thanks for your help Foocli :)

Comment: Yeah that's usually the case, you should probably change the way how you write templates: make a base template, create blocks for all css and JS files, include your navbar and footer, then extend the base for every page. Usually only base will contain imported files so that you will not run into this problem again plus it's cleaner. If you need to include different sets of scripts in other templates, overwrite the block so scripts in base will be gone.